# display comment programmatically below column on SharePoint 2007

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2007

How may i display a line of comment programmatically below an input to a column, say 'Title', on SharePoint 2007?  Users will see that comment on creation of a custom list item? Code samples much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[`SPField.Description`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.description%28v=office.12%29.aspx) serves this purpose. SharePoint displays it automatically on the item edit form.

Comment: @ Ondrej Tucny: Oh thank you! Could you please provide an example? will be delighted! :)